# How to sign out with Google+ on iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiwebview, google-plus

I am writing an application where user can login using Google+. I followed GOOGLE Developer console and successfully logged in and obtained the user profile information  through Access_Token. and i want to login through web view, but how to make sign out after login?

My Webview method

```
-(void)addWebView
{

    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?response_type=code&client_id=%@&redirect_uri=%@&scope=%@&data-requestvisibleactions=%@",client_id,callbakc,scope,visibleactions];

    self.webview = [[UIWebView alloc]init];
    self.webview.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height);
    self.webview.delegate = self;
    [self.view addSubview:self.webview];
    [self.webview  loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];


}
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView*)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest*)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType {
    //    [indicator startAnimating];
    if ([[[request URL] host] isEqualToString:@"localhost"]) {

        // Extract oauth_verifier from URL query
        NSString* verifier = nil;
        NSArray* urlParams = [[[request URL] query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];
        for (NSString* param in urlParams) {
            NSArray* keyValue = [param componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
            NSString* key = [keyValue objectAtIndex:0];
            if ([key isEqualToString:@"code"]) {
                verifier = [keyValue objectAtIndex:1];
                NSLog(@"verifier %@",verifier);
                break;
            }
        }

        if (verifier) {
            NSString *data = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"code=%@&client_id=%@&client_secret=%@&redirect_uri=%@&grant_type=authorization_code", verifier,client_id,secret,callbakc];
            NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token"];
            NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
            [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
            [request setHTTPBody:[data dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
            NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
            receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

        } else {
            // ERROR!
        }

        [webView removeFromSuperview];

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You no longer need to do this yourself. As of 2.0.0, [Google Sign-in with the Identity SDK](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/) will allow you to use a webview.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  NSError* configureError;
  [[GGLContext sharedInstance] configureWithError: &configureError];
  NSAssert(!configureError, @"Error configuring Google services: %@", configureError);
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithWebView = YES;
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].allowsSignInWithBrowser = NO;
  [GIDSignIn sharedInstance].delegate = self;
  // ...
}
```

After signing the user in, you'll receive all of the relevant details in didSignInForUser:

```
- (void)signIn    :(GIDSignIn *)signIn
  didSignInForUser:(GIDGoogleUser *)user
         withError:(NSError *)error {
  // Perform any operations on signed in user here.
  NSString *userId = user.userID;                  // For client-side use only!
  NSString *idToken = user.authentication.idToken; // Safe to send to the server
  NSString *name = user.profile.name;
  NSString *email = user.profile.email;
}
```

Later, when you want to sign the user out, just call the SignOut method on the sharedInstance singleton:

```
[GIDSignIn sharedInstance].signOut();
```

You should try out the Google Sign-in example to see a full example of how to use the SDK:

```
pod try Google
```

Comment: Hi can you send me the sample code for this library

Comment: The sample code is downloaded when you execute `pod try Google`, alternatively, you can start from here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/signin or https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/archive/master.zip